# Google Play Subscription Api: How to distinguish between refunded subscription and user-self canceled subscription?

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-developer-api, in-app-subscription

How to distinguish between refunded subscription and user-self canceled subscription?

Both shows Expiring date (expiryTimeMillis) and cancellation date (userCancellationTimeMillis) same.

I did not find a single clue to dissent those from each other, is there any?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to differentiate is keeping a record in the database!
I hope google would have a more comprehensive API in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the details of subscription purchase using 
[Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions)

```
  "kind": string,
  "startTimeMillis": string,
  "expiryTimeMillis": string,
  "autoResumeTimeMillis": string,
  "autoRenewing": boolean,
  "priceCurrencyCode": string,
  "priceAmountMicros": string,
  "introductoryPriceInfo": {
    object (IntroductoryPriceInfo)
  },
  "countryCode": string,
  "developerPayload": string,
  "paymentState": integer,
  "cancelReason": integer,
  "userCancellationTimeMillis": string,
  ...
```

where field `cancelReason` [defines](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions) the details of cancelation. Possible values are:

- 0. User canceled the subscription
- 1. Subscription was canceled by the system, for example because of a billing problem
- 2. Subscription was replaced with a new subscription
- 3. Subscription was canceled by the developer